# select query using column no instead of column name

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have table like this:

```
StartDate  Day1Hours Day2Hours Day3Hours Day4Hours Day5Hours Day6Hours Day7Hours
1/17/2010     8          8          8        8          8         8         8      
1/24/2010     8          8          0        0          10        2         2
```

How can i fetch Hours between 1/18/2010 and 1/22/2010 .

Comment: If possible, you should think about changing your database structure so that you have one row per day, not one row per week.

Comment: I am with Blorgbeard. Try to rework on database. For now this design might be looking like a quick win, but it will be very rigid for future extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a CROSS JOIN to multiple out to one row per day with appropriate hours for the row.

```
;WITH cteFixedSchema AS
(
   SELECT
      DATEADD(day, DayOffset, StartDate) AS ProperDate,
      CASE DayOffset
         WHEN 0 THEN Day1Hours
         WHEN 1 THEN Day2Hours
         WHEN 2 THEN Day3Hours
         WHEN 3 THEN Day4Hours
         WHEN 4 THEN Day5Hours
         WHEN 5 THEN Day6Hours
         WHEN 6 THEN Day7Hours
      END AS DayHours
   FROM
      MyTable M
      CROSS JOIN
      (SELECT 0 AS DayOffset UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2
         UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6) foo
)
SELECT
    SUM(DayHours)
FROM
    cteFixedSchema
WHERE
    ProperDate BETWEEN '20110118' AND '20110122'
```

This assume StartDate is a valid date(time) data type with no extra conversions needed

Comment: i have one question why you specified date as '20110118' .Is it standard format or anything else...

Comment: @Gulshan: it is safest for SQL Server http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use a map int->String which maps the day number to the column name.

C# example:

```
public class Example
{
    private static Dictionary<int, string> columns;

    static Example()
    {
        columns.Add(1, "Day1Hours");
        columns.Add(2, "Day2Hours");
        columns.Add(3, "Day3Hours");
        columns.Add(4, "Day4Hours");
        columns.Add(5, "Day5Hours");
        columns.Add(6, "Day6Hours");
        columns.Add(7, "Day7Hours");
    }

    public void queryThirdDay(string startDate)
    {
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("SELECT ");
        query.Append(columns[3]); // get third day
        query.Append(" FROM table WHERE StartDate = '");
        query.Append(startDate);
        query.Append("'");

        // query it
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @Gulshan: Added an example in C#

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments about the schema. If for whatever reason this is out of your control you can `unpivot` to get it into this schema then select from that.

```
Declare @basedata table
(
StartDate datetime,
Day1Hours int,
Day2Hours int,
Day3Hours int,
Day4Hours int,
Day5Hours int,
Day6Hours int,
Day7Hours int
)
INSERT INTO @basedata
select '20100117',8,8,8,8,8,8,8 union all
select '20100124',8,8,0,0,10,2,2

DECLARE @Start DATETIME
DECLARE @End DATETIME

SET @Start = '20100118'
SET @End = '20100122'

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, SUBSTRING(d, 4, 1) - 1, StartDate),
       Hours
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM   @basedata b
        WHERE  b.StartDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -7, @Start) AND
                                   DATEADD(DAY, 7, @End))
       filtered UNPIVOT (Hours FOR d IN 
    (Day1Hours, Day2Hours, Day3Hours, Day4Hours, Day5Hours, Day6Hours, Day7Hours) ) AS unpvt
WHERE  DATEADD(DAY, SUBSTRING(d, 4, 1) - 1, StartDate) BETWEEN @Start AND @End
```